# Kendo Datepicker How can i show year range at on click of datepicker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

i am using the kendo datepicker,i want to display year range like (1990-1990) when the calendar open, rather than showing the todays date like(January 6).

Answer (score 1):

Use `depth` and `start` (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-depth):

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    depth: "year",
    start: "year"
});
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    depth: "decade",
    start: "decade"
});
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    depth: "century",
    start: "century"
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i needed the "CENTURY" which display year range when the datepicker opens at first time.

Comment: @NagarajM replace "year" with "century", it it supports only range from 1900 to 2099 with 10year step

Comment: thank you,i have  replace "year" with "century",its working.

Comment: @NagarajM there is also "decade" with step 1year

Comment: thanks,"decade" which i needed. i want to remove "k-picker-wrap" class default style,is it possible for kendo datepicker which is  built in style.